# Critical listening examples for compressors and digital filters?

Tags: compression, filter, listening

I'm looking for listening examples for the following applications:

-Compressors usage (what to listen for when changing parameters such as ratio, attack, release time, etc). I've found some material on youtube but nothing consistent and much less comprehensive.

-Pre and Post-ring on digital filters (or linear phase vs min phase filters). I've found nothing like these.

Does anybody knows of existing examples for online to practice my critical listening skills?

Answer (score 1):

[This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1U2hZHHFY0) offers a nice explanation and some audio tracks at the end where they adjust parameters which the track plays. Its a nice little instructional. I have not found one on filters but there are so many filters out there you may have better luck picking a specific filter or plug in and looking for a video on it.